# How to append data-mage-init in html

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento

I have append the html content in particular div.

```
styleBasedProducts += "<div class='row image-full'><div class='col-md-12 home-title text-center'><div><span class='light'>Style Based</span><span class='heavier'> Products</span></div><p aria-hidden='true'></p></div></div>";
```

And also init the custom js in this '.image-full' div.

How to do this?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your single-line HTML, but I think you have one more opening `<div>` than closing `</div>` . But I don't know if that's related to your problem. It's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: i need to initiate the custom js file for  '.image-full'  class ...How to do that

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what you mean.

Comment: i need to frame that html like this <div class="image-full" data-mage-init='{"imageResponsive": {}}'> in js file

Comment: OK. There are quite a few answers on [magento.se] that seem to be talking about this, have you looked there?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
styleBasedProducts += "you html here";

jQuery('.your_div_class').append(styleBasedProducts);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(selector).append(content,function(index,html))
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp